# How can I edit a Deployment without modify the file manually?

Tags: kubernetes

I have defined a Deployment for my app:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapp-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: myapp
        image: 172.20.34.206:5000/myapp_img:2.0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

Now, if I want update my app's image 2.0 to 3.0, I do this:

1. `$ kubectl edit deployment/myapp-deployment`
2. `vim` is open. I change the image version from 2.0 to 3.0 and save.

How can it be automated? Is there a way to do it just running a command? Something like:

```
$ kubectl edit deployment/myapp-deployment --image=172.20.34.206:5000/myapp:img:3.0
```

I thought using Kubernetes API REST but I don't understand the [documentation](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/HEAD/docs/api-reference/extensions/v1beta1/operations.html).

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You could do it via the REST API using the [PATCH verb](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/devel/sig-architecture/api-conventions.md#patch-operations). However, an easier way is to use [kubectl patch](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#patch). The following command updates your app's tag:

```
kubectl patch deployment myapp-deployment -p \
  '{"spec":{"template":{"spec":{"containers":[{"name":"myapp","image":"172.20.34.206:5000/myapp:img:3.0"}]}}}}'
```

According to [the documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#patch), YAML format should be accepted as well. See [Kubernetes issue #458](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes.github.io/issues/458) though (and in particular [this comment](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes.github.io/issues/458#issuecomment-216371921)) which may hint at a problem.

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting an error but I'm going to post another question

Comment: To be honest, I didn't have the time to try the command out myself yet. Will try to do so later and come back to you!

Comment: My JSON spec wasn't completely correct: The container definition is more deeply nested. I updated my answer and double-checked it's working correctly.

Comment: Is there a way to also update automatically the yaml when patch?

Answer (score 34):

There is a `set image` command which may be useful in simple cases

> Update existing container image(s) of resources.
>   Possible resources include (case insensitive):
>   pod (po), replicationcontroller (rc), deployment (deploy), daemonset (ds), job, replicaset (rs)
>
> `kubectl set image (-f FILENAME | TYPE NAME) CONTAINER_NAME_1=CONTAINER_IMAGE_1 ... CONTAINER_NAME_N=CONTAINER_IMAGE_N`
>
> http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_set_image/

```
$ kubectl set image deployment/nginx-deployment nginx=nginx:1.9.1
deployment "nginx-deployment" image updated
```

http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/deployments/

Answer (score 4):

(I would have posted this as a comment if I had enough reputation)

Yes, as per http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_patch/ both JSON and YAML formats are accepted.

But I see that all the examples there are using JSON format.
Filed https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes.github.io/issues/458 to add a YAML format example.

Comment: I amended my answer with links to the documentation and the issue you created. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I have recently built a tool to automate deployment updates when new images are available, it works with Kubernetes and Helm:

https://github.com/rusenask/keel

You only have to label your deployments with Keel policy like `keel.sh/policy=major` to enable major version updates, more info in the readme. Works similarly with Helm, no additional CLI/UI required.

Comment: so here is where keel started, nice.