# Kubernetes: Error from server when edit Deployment

Tags: kubernetes

I have this `Deployment`:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: app
        image: 172.20.34.206:5000/myapp_img:1.0
        ports:
    - containerPort: 8080
```

Now, I want to upgrade the image from 1.0 to 2.0, so I do this:

```
$ kubectl patch deployment app-deployment -p '{"spec":{"containers":[{"name":"myapp","image":"172.20.34.206:5000/myapp_img:2.0"}]}}'
```

But I get this error:

> Error from server: the server rejected our request for an unknown
>   reason (patch deployments.extensions app-deployment)

If I edit the `Deployment` via `kubectl edit deployment/app-deployment`, it works properly.

Comment: Does adding `-v` (and possibly another integer right after it to increase verbosity level) give you details?

Comment: Couldn't repro on HEAD (what's 2.0, did you mean kube 1.2?). Note that your yaml is wrong, "containerPort" is a field in the list of ports.

Comment: @PrashanthB: 2.0 is referring to the updated image tag, not the Kubernetes version.

Comment: Please try the (updated) answer I gave in http://stackoverflow.com/a/36924484/420061. If that's not working, please post the output of `kubectl get deployment app-deployment -o yaml`.

Comment: @TimoReimann Thanks again, it is working :D