# How to automate kubernetes deployments?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm creating a [kubernetes deployment](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/deployments/) using the following command:

```
kubectl run my-app --image=ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/my-app:v1 -l name=my-app --replicas=1
```

Now I want to update `my-app` to v2. Following [this blog post](http://blog.kubernetes.io/2016/04/using-deployment-objects-with.html) it seems the recommended way is to use:

```
kubectl edit deployment/my-app
```

The problem is this wants to open a text editor so Im not sure how I can automate this task in my continuous deployment environment. Ideally, I'd like to run a command something like:

```
kubectl edit deployment/update --image=ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/my-app:v2
```

How can I script this so that it doesn't open the text editor?

Answer (score 0):

Please see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36924484/420061) to the very similar question [How can I edit a Deployment without modify the file manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36920171/how-can-i-edit-a-deployment-without-modify-the-file-manually/36924484). It involves running `kubectl patch`.