# How can I fix Edit cancelled, no changes made in shell

Tags: shell, kubernetes, sh, fish

I run

```
kubectl edit deployment
```

to change the version of one of my pods (this commands opens a temp file in my text editor and then I usually edit and close this temp file) and even before I *close* this temp file in my text editor I can see the following note in my bash.

```
Edit cancelled, no changes made.
```

It was OK before I installed *fish* and I tried to switch to *bash* but it doesn't help either.

How can I fix it?

Comment: what editor is supposed to launch?

Comment: I use sublime and it does launch. But by the time it launches I can already see `Edit cancelled, no changes made.`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Things like this are most likely caused by it opening an editor that forks off instead of staying.

That means you'll want to set $EDITOR to an editor that does wait. E.g. `nano`, `vim` or `emacs` should work, and e.g. if you use sublime text you'll have to use `subl -w` to explicitly tell it to wait.

It's not quite clear which shell you're running at the moment. If it's bash, run `export EDITOR="subl -w"`, in fish run `set -gx EDITOR subl -w` (or `"subl -w"` if you use fish < 3.0).

Comment: This works for VSCode - `KUBE_EDITOR="code -w" kubectl edit ...`

Comment: @billett I still get the same error, even after restarting powershell on win. Do you know what might be wrong?

Comment: after executing the command, what operation needs to be performed once we edit the file and saved

Comment: @Spartan after that you need to close the editor, because that is what the command is waiting for.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but unfortunately the edit operation dint get executed after closing the file :(

Comment: it doesn't work with `vim`, I came here to get a solution for the error and I always use `vim`, so I should not be here at all. With vim the following happens:
```
error: deployments.apps "tymik-test-nginx-deployment" is invalid
A copy of your changes has been stored to "/tmp/kubectl-edit-542433319.yaml"
error: Edit cancelled, no valid changes were saved.
```
Could you remove vim from the examples in the answer?

Comment: No, it typically *does* work with vim (which is a terminal editor, where it makes no sense not to wait). Using vim as $EDITOR is a very common thing to do. You have a different problem.

Answer (score 8):

A refinement to the ample answer provided by [@faho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3150338/faho).

An approach with the $EDITOR variable achieves the goal but changes the default command-line editor. This might affect other programs dependent on this setting (e.g. crontab, edquota).

It'd be better to rely on the $KUBE_EDITOR variable. For example for the one-time use you might try:

```
KUBE_EDITOR="nano" kubectl edit deploy/hello-world
```

(Please see [Editing Resources](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#editing-resources))

Comment: In this case, $EDITOR is faulty for *most things*. A $EDITOR that does not stop will also confuse e.g. git, so you shouldn't use one.

Comment: If you really cannot use editor, you can also just try patching deployment. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36920171/how-can-i-edit-a-deployment-without-modify-the-file-manually

Comment: This works fine. Tested on xubuntu VM via mobaxterm

Answer (score 5):

With vim, when you try to save it saves an edited copy which is specified in `/tmp/` path, along with the error message, when you quit the editor.

This is equivalent to using `get` the resource, edit it in text editor, and then apply the resource with the updated version:

```
kubectl get deployment my-nginx -o yaml > /tmp/nginx.yaml
vim /tmp/nginx.yaml


kubectl apply -f /tmp/nginx.yaml
deployment.apps/my-nginx configured
```

then remove the file

```
rm /tmp/nginx.yaml
```

So basically use `apply` on the file saved in the `/tmp/<file.yaml>`

Comment: This worked for me! Additional note - when I was using the `/tmp/kubectl-edit-NUMBERS.yaml` and apply it, I had an error, so first command from this answer is mandatory! In case someone else tries to edit the file generated initially by `kubectl edit` with `vim` - it will not work.

Answer (score 1):

This issue may also happen when changes made by you are not picked by an kubectl eg. because of incorrect YAML.

- Please make other change that you are sure of.
- After saving check if still getting the same problem

**Example issue replication:**

- the spec.selector.app: xxx" is invalid as it is duplicated;
- the last one will remain; the first will be ignored.
- so if you just added the first one - it no changes will be made.

> ```
> spec:
>   clusterIP: 10.152.183.151
>   clusterIPs:
>   - 10.152.183.151
>   ports:
>   - port: 80
>     protocol: TCP
>     targetPort: 80
>   selector:
>     app: xxx
>     app: rng
> ```