# How to use VS Code as $VISUAL editor in Fish Shell, spec. `funced`

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, fish

I'd like to edit existing fish functions in VS Code, but can't seem to get funced to behave as expected.

Here's what I've tried:

```sh
$ set VISUAL code     # also tried /usr/local/bin/code
$ funced print_bool
Editor exited but the function was not modified
```

```sh
$ funced print_bool -e code   # or /usr/local/bin/code
Editor exited but the function was not modified
```

In each case, VS Code opens an empty file titled "print_bool.fish"…

[image]

…however, `print_bool` isn't an empty function:

```sh
$ funced print_bool -i
$ print_bool> function print_bool --argument arg
    if eval $arg
        echo true
    else
        echo false
    end
end
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I fix Edit cancelled, no changes made in shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56811177/how-can-i-fix-edit-cancelled-no-changes-made-in-shell)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use `code` as a synchronous editor, pass `--wait`:

```
set -x VISUAL 'code --wait'
```

otherwise the command will return immediately before the file is saved, so fish will conclude the file has not been changed.