# K9s edits are not applied when using neovim

Tags: kubernetes, vim, neovim

When editing the yaml definition of a resource the changes are not applied in k9s.

I see that neovim is saving the changes I made to a file in `/tmp` but after exiting with `:wq` the changes are not being applied in k9s.

When I do the same thing with e.g. nano as editor, the changes are being applied immediately.

I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65954205/13693791) to a similar question that says the file in /tmp/ would need to be applied (using kubectl apply) which does work but I would like to have a similar experience to the nano case, where the changes are saved and applied immediately.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a case of Vim renaming the file during the process of writing the buffer to disk.

If so, you need to adjust `:help 'backupcopy'`:

```
" in your vimrc
set backupcopy=yes
```

Comment: Thanks but setting this actually didn't help in my case - I did figure out by now that the problem must be related to a plugin that I use. When I set `EDITOR` to `nvim -u NONE` it actually works just fine.

Comment: I can't speak for Neovim.