# Replace output of a command using sed

Tags: bash, sed

On a running a customised kubectl command in bash terminal, it opens a yaml file in the vim editor, but i'm trying to replace a string without having to open an editor. (command is part of a bash script.)

```
kubectl deploy apps edit namespace | sed  -i "s/version-tag:2.4.0.9/version-tag:2.4.0.10/"

Error:

sed: no input files
Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal


    kubectl deploy apps edit namespace | sed  -i -e "s/version-tag:2.4.0.9/version-tag:2.4.0.10/"

Error:
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `-' and no replacement happens.
```

I tried other options, by referring the suggestions on the forums, no luck though.. Where am I going wrong.

Comment: Remove `-i`, it is for inline file replacing.

Comment: it opens a vim editor which I dont want, as I have to run this command as part of the shell script :(

Comment: how about [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36920171/how-can-i-edit-a-deployment-without-modify-the-file-manually)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the -i in the sed command. This should work:

```
kubectl deploy apps edit namespace | sed "s/version-tag:2.4.0.9/version-tag:2.4.0.10/"
```

Comment: Forgot to add that, tried that as well - but it opens a vim editor which I dont want, as I have to run this command as part of the shell script.